# pdo disconnect from database in class

Tags: php, class, pdo, disconnect

I wrote a class for PDO and need to disconnect PDO => ( I don't know how to do it )

I don't know code wrote is structurally correct?!

use `$this->returnconn();` for db connection

Please guide me...

Sample code:

```
class conn {
    public $inner;
    public function returnconn() {
            $CONF = $TMPL = array();
            // The MySQL credentials
            $CONF['host'] = 'localhost';
            $CONF['user'] = 'root';
            $CONF['pass'] = '';
            $CONF['name'] = 'cmss';
            $dsn ="mysql:host=".$CONF['host'].";dbname=".$CONF['name']."";
                try{
                    $conn = new PDO($dsn,$CONF['user'],$CONF['pass']);
                    $conn ->exec("SET CHARACTER SET UTF8");
                    }catch(PDOException $e){
                        die($e->getMessage());
                    }
            return $conn;
    }

    public function select(){

        switch ($this->inner->switch){
                case "select":

                    $sql="SELECT ".$this->inner->todo." FROM ".$this->inner->table." WHERE ".$this->inner->sql."";
                    $result=$this->returnconn()->prepare($sql);
                       /*
                         * this->returnconn();
                        */
                    $result->execute();
                    if($result->rowCount()<=0){
                    return '{"msg":"empty "}';
                    }else{
                    return $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                    }
        break;
        }
    }

}

/* receive data */
$obj = new conn;
$iner = array();
$iner['table'] = 'category';
$iner['switch'] ='select';
$iner['todo'] = '*';
$iner['sql'] = '`id` IS NOT NULL ORDER BY `id` ASC';
$in = json_decode(json_encode($iner));
$obj ->inner = $in;
echo json_encode($obj ->select());
```

Do need a function to disconnect?

Comment: Unless you're using a persistent connection you can generally leave connections to be cleaned up automatically.

Comment: This code is of low quality. However, _if it works_ you could post it [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) to get it reviewed. That is more a forum for guidance on coding than Stack Overflow.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton didn't you write a database class of your own? ;-)

Comment: Hey milad, kindly read my article on the [PDO classes common mistakes](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes)

Comment: @YourCommonSense Yes I did ;-)

Comment: LOL and @YourCommonSense and GrumpyCrouton